# Can I calculate the integral WITHOUT calculating the interpolating polynomial?

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, interpolation

Suppose, $f(x)$ is the polynomial of degree $2$ with $f(x_j)=y_j$ , $j=1,2,3$
with $x_1<x_2<x_3$

> Can I calculate $\int_{x_1}^{x_3} f(x)dx$ WITHOUT calculating the interpolating polynomial ?

If the nodes are equidistant, I can use the simpson-rule, but does an exact formula exist in the general case ?

A method working also for more nodes (and an interpolating polynomial with higher degree) would be particularly nice!

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "without the interpolating polynomial". Sure there is a formula which only involves the data...but you cook up that formula by passing through the actual interpolating polynomial.

Comment: I am looking for a method similar to the Newton-method to find the interpolating polynomial ; a scheme which can be easily handled.

Answer (score 0):

*Yes you can*, it is the main idea behind [Newton-Cotes formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Newton-CotesFormulas.html) for numerical integration. 
With three points of interpolation fulfilling $x_1=\frac{x_0+x_2}{2}$, the machinery is known as [Simpson's Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpsonsRule.html).
You may easily adapt the proof given in the linked pages if $x_1\neq\frac{x_0+x_2}{2}$.